# How can I find the curves in the problem?

Tags: calculus, geometry

It's the first exercise in this [book](http://archive.org/stream/courseinmathemat01gouruoft#page/31/mode/2up) (It has a drawing).

> Let $ \rho = f(\theta) $ be the equation of a plane curve in polar coordinates.  Through the pole $O$ draw a line perpendicular to the radius vector $OM$, and let $T$ and $N$ be the points where this line cuts the tangent and the normal.  Find expressions for the distances $OT$, $ON$, $MN$, and $MT$ in terms of $f(\theta)$ and $f'(\theta)$.
>
> Find the curves for which each of these distances, in turn, is constant.

I tried to find the curve with $OT$ being constant.

$$\begin{aligned}
M (\rho\cos \theta, \rho\sin\theta)\\
T (k\sin\theta, k\cos\theta)\\
\frac{y_T-y_M}{x_T-x_M} = \frac{dy_M}{dx_M} \\
(k\cos\theta-\rho\sin\theta)(\rho'\cos\theta-\rho\sin\theta)=\\(k\sin\theta-\rho\cos\theta)(\rho'\sin\theta+\rho\cos\theta)
\end{aligned}$$

What should I do next?

Comment: You need to find the point $T$ (and likewise N, M) in terms of $f(\theta), f'(\theta)$ first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll solve just the case for which $OT$ is constant. The missing cases you can easily complete.

Let $\vec {r}$ the position vector of point M, and $\vec{i}$ and $\vec{j}$ the versors of axes $x$ and $y$ respectively. Let the set of vectors $\{\vec{u},\vec{v}\}$ an orthonormal basis and $\rho =f(\theta)$.

See the figure below:

[image: Curve]

So
$$\vec {r} = f(\theta) \vec {u} \quad (I)$$
$$\vec {u}= \cos(\theta)\vec {i} +\sin(\theta) \vec {j}$$
$$\vec {v}= \dfrac{d\vec{u}}{d\theta} = -\sin(\theta)\vec {i} +\cos(\theta) \vec {j}$$
Let $\vec {t}$ a tangent vector at point M. The vector $\vec {t}$ can be defined as:
$$\vec {t} = \dfrac{d\vec{r}}{d\theta}.$$

So
$$\vec {t} = f'(\theta) \vec {u} + f(\theta) \vec{v}.$$
Let's calculate $OT$ now.

We know that
$$\overrightarrow{OT}=\vec {r} + \overrightarrow{MT}.\quad (1)$$
But
$$\overrightarrow{MT}= \lambda \vec{t} \quad (2)$$
and
$$\overrightarrow{OT}= \mu \vec{v}. \quad(3)$$

So using equations $(I)$, $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ we get:
$$f(\theta) \vec{u} + \lambda[f'(\theta) \vec{u} + f(\theta) \vec{v}]= \mu \vec{v} \Rightarrow$$
$$(f(\theta)+\lambda f'(\theta)) \vec{u} + \lambda f(\theta) \vec{v}= \mu \vec{v}. \quad (4) $$
It follows that
$$\lambda = - \frac{f(\theta)}{f'(\theta)} \quad (5)$$
and
$$\mu = - \frac{f^2(\theta)}{f'(\theta)}. \quad (6)$$
Therefore
$$OT= \frac{f^2(\theta)}{f'(\theta)}. \quad (7)$$
As $\triangle NMT$ is a right triangle we can easily calculate $ON$, $MN$, and $MT$.
For example:

We know that
$$ON \cdot OT = OM^2, \quad (8) $$
then using $(7)$ and $(8)$ we get:
$$ON = f'(\theta). \quad (9)$$
If we want a curve for which $OT$ is constant ($k$) then
$$\frac{f^2(\theta)}{f'(\theta)}=k \Rightarrow$$
$$\Rightarrow k \dfrac{df}{d\theta}=f^2(\theta) \Rightarrow$$
$$\Rightarrow k \frac{d\rho}{\rho^2}= d\theta \Rightarrow$$
$$\Rightarrow -k \rho^{-1}=\theta + C$$
and we are done.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain a bit why $\vec {v}= \dfrac{d\vec{u}}{d\theta}$ but $\vec {t} = \dfrac{d\vec{r}}{d\theta}$?  And what tools did you use to draw the beautiful figure?

Comment: @zjk. You're welcome. If you take the derivative of a versor you'll get another versor which is orthogonal to the first one.
$$\vec {u} \cdot \vec {u} =1 \Rightarrow \dfrac{d (\vec {u} \cdot \vec {u})}{d \theta} \Rightarrow$$
$$2 \vec {u} \cdot \dfrac{d \vec {u}}{d \theta}=0 \Rightarrow \vec {u} \perp \dfrac{d \vec {u}}{d \theta}$$

Comment: @zjk.
As regards to $\dfrac{d \vec {r}}{d \theta}$, if you define two points $M$ and $M'$ as $M = O + \vec {r}(\theta)$ and $M' = O + \vec{r}(\theta + \Delta \theta)$ you will get a straight line defined by $MM'$ which is a secant line of the curve $\rho = f(\theta)$. When $\Delta \theta \to 0$, then $M' \to M$ and the line defined by $MM'$ approaches to a tangent line. So if you calculate $\dfrac {d \vec{r}}{d \theta} = \lim_{\Delta \theta \to 0}\frac{\vec {r}(\theta +  \Delta \theta)-\vec {r}(\theta)}{\Delta \theta}$, you will ge a tangent vector to the curve at point $M$.

Comment: @zjk.
As regards to the figure, it was drawn using Geogebra.